# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://cardano.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 3):

I'm excited about this. I see that Marek nominated himself. I followed his lead and did the same.

Once the election is over, I propose to possibly work with the Town Hall folks to bring more directed attention to this StackExchange by possibly feature some (unanswered) Questions.

I'm excited to be part of this journey.

Comment: Great, Matthias. we need to get moderators in stack pool and developer telegram channel to divert users here. Answers are reviewed in a much better way in stake exchange.